# Programming with threads, what is the benefit?

Tags: multithreading, performance

Given a single core CPU, what is the benefit to coding using threads?

At least with the Java implementation, and it seems intuitive to naturally extend to any other language considering the single core restriction, you may have several threads performing various actions but the processes are time-limited and switched.

**Given process A and process B:**

What is the benefit of performing half of process A, finish process B, and then finish the second half of process A VS performing process A then B?

It seems that the switching between the threads would introduce time delays that would prolong the overall completion time of both processes VS not switching and just completing A then B.

Comment: Loads of reasons. I/O bound tasks benefit from threading (especially network applications). Hyperthreaded processors may speed up multithreaded applications even on a single core. Threads can be instructed to wait (block) and wake up on specific events, enabling event-driven programming...

Comment: Event driven programming is a wonderful benefit. So, for a simple implementation - would the main program be on a single thread while an event-thread would disrupt the program flow and run some specified task?

Comment: Other way around. The "main thread" runs short pieces of code which respond to use input. The computation and heavy lifting code runs in lower-priority threads. The main thread wakes up every time an event comes in, processes it through UI code, and goes back to sleep.

Comment: @nneonneo: Just a comment about event driven programming. Threads are not needed for that. MUD engines (text based MMORPGs from the 1990s) were single threaded and event driven. I use MUDs as an example since I worked on several.

Comment: @ZanLynx: not necessary, but real nice to have. Polling for events while doing heavy computations is really tough.

Answer (score 6):

The reason to use threads on a single-core system is simply to allow processes that would otherwise use all the CPU to be preempted by other tasks that need to get done sooner. The most common reason to make a system multi-threaded is to have a responsive user interface even while performing long calculations.

Of course, any operation can take a long time (reading a file, accessing a database, resizing a photo, recalculating a spreadsheet), and those operations can be performed on a separate thread to allow the thread responding to user input to operate the whole time.

Twenty years ago, for example, it was rare to have a multi-CPU system or an OS that allowed multi-threading, so nearly every program was single-threaded and there were many frameworks created to allow systems to have UIs and still do I/O. The standard mechanism for this is an event loop, where all events (UI, network, timers, etc.) are processed in a big loop.

This type of system means that the UI is held up during things like file I/O and calculations. In order to not hold up the UI too much, you have to do the I/O in chunks (say, read the file 4k at a time), processing any incoming UI events between chunks. This is really just a hack to keep the system running, but it's hard to make the system run smoothly like this because you don't know how often you need to process events.

The solution is to have a separate thread to recalculate your spreadsheet or write your file. That way the OS can give those threads fair timeslices while still preempting them to run the UI, allowing the UI to always be responsive.

Comment: Great! This too makes great sense. Constant refreshing of the UI while other tasks are performed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An executing thread is not necessarily doing anything useful. The canonical example is reading from disk -- that data isn't going to be there for another few milliseconds, during which time the processor would be sitting unused. Threads allow one piece of the program to use the CPU while other pieces of the program are waiting for operations to complete.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons. Wikipedia gives a decent overview on its [page about threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Multithreading).

Here's a few OTOH:

- I/O bound tasks benefit from threading (especially network applications).
- Hyperthreaded processors may speed up multithreaded applications even on a single core.
- Threads can be instructed to wait (block) and wake up on specific events, enabling responsive event-driven programming.

Answer (score 2):

If your program has to do several things "at the same time" then threads are a good way to go, particularly is some of those tasks are quite long running. Otherwise you find yourself writing code that looks like an operating system scheduler inside your program, which is always a waste of time if the OS underneath you has a perfectly good one already. You'd find that your source code was mostly 'scheduler' and not much 'program', which is very inelegant. A good threaded program can be very elegant and economic in source code, which makes oneself look good and saves time.

Some run times get/got it wrong. In the early days of Ada the runtime environment would do its own thread scheduling, and it was never very satisfactory. That was partly due to the fact that whilst the Ada language spec included the concept of threads, the OSes we had back then quite often didn't provide them. Ada got a lot better when the compiler writers started using the underlying OS threads instead.

Similarly Python doesn't really properly use the underlying OS threads; it spoils it with the Global Interpreter Lock. Python has sidestepped the whole issue by going for multiprocessing instead (not necessarily a good thing on Windows hosts...).

Early versions of Windows didn't do threads either, they did cooperative multitasking. This depended on each process in the whole machine calling any OS routine at least now and then. Each OS routine would first consult the 'scheduler' to see if anything else was waiting to run before getting on with whatever it was supposed to be doing on behalf of the program. There were many terrible programs back then that wouldn't play ball and hogged the entire machine. You couldn't get on with playing a game of Solitaire when something else embarked on a length calculation.

Answer (score 1):

What's the mental model of your program?

IF it depends on multiple external inputs that can happen in unpredictable orders, and if what you want to do in response to those inputs is not simple and can overlap in time ...

THEN it makes sense to devote a separate thread to each input request, and have that thread perform the response needed by that request.

So, for example, if your program is waiting for input requests from an external channel, and each request must trigger its own protocol of outgoing and incoming messages, it can very much simplify the code to create a new thread (or re-use an old one) for each request.

Somehow people seem to enter the workforce thinking that threads are only there for speed (through parallelism).
That's one use, provided it allows multiple CPU chips to get cranking,
but it is by no means the only use.